# dask loading multiple parquet files with different column selections

Tags: pandas, dask, parquet, dask-distributed

I want to use Dask to load specific columns from many parquet files that are stored in different directories and each parquet needs to load different columns. I want to use Dask so that I can use multiple cores on a single machine. I see how you can pass a list of files or wildcards to `dd.read_parquet` to indicate multiple files (e.g. `*.parquet`), but I do not see a way of passing different sets of columns to be read for each file. I'm wondering if this can be done using `dask.delayed`.

My specific situation is:

I'm storing large single cell gene expression datasets (~30,000 rows/genes by ~10,000 columns/cells) as parquet files in different directories. Each directory has two parquet files 1) the large gene expression data (cells as columns) and 2) cell metadata (cells as rows and cell metadata as columns). I'm using the smaller metadata parquet files to look up the columns/cells that I need in the larger file. For instance, I'll find all the cells that are of a specific cell type using the metadata parquet file, then load only those cells from the larger file. I'm able to do this using Pandas, but I would like to use Dask for parallelism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can do this using [Pandas `.read_parquet`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html#pandas.read_parquet), while [specifying columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#parquet) (see the very last code example), then one possible approach is to delay your existing Pandas-specific approach by replacing

```
pd.read_parquet(..., columns=[list_of_cols])
```

by

```
dask.delayed(pd.read_parquet)(..., columns=[list_of_cols])
```

as you had suggested.

**EDIT**

I had to do something similar for a single directory of paired `.csv` files - metadata and corresponding spectra. My filtering logic was minimal so I created a Python dict whose keys were the metadata logic (that produced a file name) and the value was the list of columns. I looped over the dictionary key-value paris and

- read in the corresponding list of columns from the associated spectrum file using `dd.read_csv(..., columns=[list_of_cols])`
- appended the `ddf` to a blank list (obviously followed by `dd.concat()` to vertically concatenate them all together after the loop)

In my case, though, the metadata contents changed in a predictable manner which is why I could programmatically assemble the dict using [dictionary comprehension](http://cmdlinetips.com/2018/01/5-examples-using-dict-comprehension).

Comment: What to do if read_parquet does not fit into memory, though?

Comment: Try to filter the data when the file is being loaded. `pd.read_parquet()` accepts a `filters` argument. Maybe this can be used to reduce the size of the data so that it does fit into memory? See an example [here](https://blog.datasyndrome.com/python-and-parquet-performance-e71da65269ce).

Comment: Been there: It helps in some places, but still dask is only interesting to me in the first place if also the resulting data frame is too big to fit into memory.

Comment: I think I caused a bit of consufion - in my previous comment I assumed `pd.read_parquet` was being used. It your data fits in memory then `pd.read_parquet` works fine. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: If data does not fit in memory, then one approach is use `dd.read_parquet` to load each file into a separate `ddf`, clean data in each `ddf` separately and combine all cleaned `ddf`s into `ddf_combined`. In loading and cleaning, there is no need to compute a result with `ddf_combined.compute()` so the individual `ddf`s do not have to fit in memory. In the analysis step, try to use a reduction operation (eg. `ddf_reduced = ddf_combined.groupby(...)`) to reduce `ddf_combined` to a manageable size (that will fit in memory) before calling `ddf_reduced.compute()`.

Comment: A custom `load`-`clean`-`analyse` pipeline is shown in dask [docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/custom-graphs.html#example). A simple example is on slides 39-41 [here](https://www.slideshare.net/ASIDataScience/automated-data-exploration-building-efficient-analysis-pipelines-with-dask). Data reduction is a best practice [from Dask docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html#reduce-and-then-use-pandas). In the `analyse` step, if you can find a reasonable data reduction then only the **reduced** data frame has to fit in memory. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @edesz. I think this is the way to go! Just a word of warning: Currently working on sth like this, but it is not really easy if your source is consisting of a few thousand parquet file. The cleaning and repartitioning is really the interesting part here. Our workflow at the moment roughly generates 1 million tasks for this, which is really annoying really bothers the scheduler. The load-clean-analyse graph simply gets to big itself by using the building read_parquet. So funnily also this aproach can hit its limits.

Comment: Yes, that is a great point. Try to divide the tasks into batches - see the `dask.delayed` docs [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html#avoid-too-many-tasks). It will probably depend on your data, but batching could help a bit.